# Slide to Image Based on URL Hash or Tab Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dynamic, tabs

I want to make a slider change to a certain slide/image, based on 2 things:

1. The URL
2. The tab that was clicked

If someone has come to the site via ../tabs/#contact, then the slider needs to slide to the 2nd image.

If some has come to the site via ../tabs/#about, then the slider needs to slide to the 1st image.

The same needs to happen is someone clicks the tabs.

If someone clicks the About tab, the slider will slide to the 1st slide or if they click the Contact tab, then it slides to the 2nd image.

Basically, I have a tight deadline. I need to know if anyone has done anything like this before and what would be the quickest way to approach it!

Last year I wrote a similar script to load dynamic content based on what the URL was or when a link with a hash tag was clicked. However, I don't have enough time to write a complex script like that for this project! Is there a simple way to do what I have described above!

```
        //load data when the link is clicked

function loadProfile() {
$('.profileID').each(function() {
        var fp = $(this).html().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,"-").replace("\'","") + "-card";
        /*alert(fp);*/
        $.get("ag-cms.php?fakeParameter=" + fp, function(data) {
            var cardID = this.url.replace("ag-cms.php?fakeParameter=", "");
            var card = $("#" + cardID, data).html();
            $(".profileID:not(:has(div)):eq(0)").html(card);
            $(".extraInfo").hide(); 
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").live('click', function() {

var titleTarget = $(this).attr("title");
document.title = 'Albert Goodman - Chartered Accountants - ' + titleTarget;   
$('#loader').html("<strong>Loading</strong> - " + titleTarget);
$('.dynamicContent, .sideBar').fadeOut("fast", function() {
$('#loader').fadeIn("fast");
});

if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("#") != -1){
var target = $(this).attr("href");      
$('#dynamicContent').load('ag-cms.php ' + target, function() {
$('#loader').hide();
$('.contactInfoBox').load('ag-cms.php #allProfiles p' );    
loadProfile();
});
};

$(window).hashchange();
});});

//load data when page loads

var ahash;
$(window).load(function () {

ahash = location.hash;
$.get('../ag-cms.php?ref='+ahash, function(data) { 

if( $(ahash, data).length == 0 && ahash != "") { 
$('#dynamicContent').load('ag-cms.php #error', function() { 
$('#error #message').append("The link <strong>" + ahash + "</strong> is not valid");
$('#loader').hide();
});}

else if( ahash != ""){ 
$('#dynamicContent').load('ag-cms.php ' + ahash, function() {
$('#loader').hide();
$('.contactInfoBox').load('ag-cms.php #allProfiles p' );
loadProfile();
});
}

else {
$('#dynamicContent').load('ag-cms.php #home', function() {
$('#theNews').load('news.php .titleBrief' );
$('#theEvents').load('events.php .titleBrief' );
$('#loader').hide();
});
};
});
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems? Reading the hash part of the URL or changing the slider?

Comment: I've tried a few things. Is this something you're good at? See this link... [jQuery Hash Tags](https://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&q=what+is+a+troll)

Comment: Last year I wrote a script to dynamically load content based on what was clicked and what the URL was (see below code). I'm guessing this should be a lot easier; however, I have never tried directly manipulating a plugin slider in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Juhana I'm curious where exactly you're having problems, and like @Aleks I'm also curious what you've tried so far?

All you need to do is check the hash on page load, if one is set and there's a link in your tabs pointing to the hash then click that link (using jQuery's `click()`). Second thing you need to do is make it so that when a tab is clicked, you also click the slider-links (`div.slidecontrolls a`).

Basically something like:

```
// Get all the tabs
var tabs = jQuery('#wp-tabs-1').find('li a');

// When clicking a tab
tabs.click(function () {
    // Find out which tab was clicked
    var which = tabs.index(this);

    // Click the corresponding link in the slider
    jQuery('div.slidecontrolls').find('a').eq(which).click();
});

// If there's a link in the tabs pointing to the current hash - click it
var hash    = window.location.hash;
var hashTab = tabs.filter('[href="' + hash + '"]');

if (hashTab.length) {
    hashTab.click();
}
```

Edit: As your tab plugin takes care of clicking the appropriate tab if a hash is set, you could change `hashTab.click()` to `jQuery('div.slidecontrolls').find('a').eq(tabs.index(hashTab)).click()` to only click the slider link.

Comment: Thank @powerbuoy

This is heading in the right direction. I'm going to adapt it to try and work on my page later. I'll let you know how it goes :o)

Comment: I actually ran that exact code in the console on your page and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing the referrer to get the address coming from? document.referrer as for the tabs I would think you could have an onclick event that passes the tab ID in and then selects the appropriate part in the slider..